# Store sensor data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, rest, raspberry-pi, iot

I'm working with Raspberry Pi trying to send the sensor data by using REST API back to Node.js (Express) and then store or update data inside MongoDB overtime. Since I have to work with many devices, how can I store data accordingly to its device. Is it a good idea to override objectId as raspberry pi serial no. and request POST/PUT to update its data overtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Device` key in the model of database.

So for every device there will be a separate document with its own information (unique or having your raspberry pi serial no) .

You can edit/delete etc the particular document by referencing `Device` without interrupting mongoose ObjectId